# How to parse list of files using argparse.FileType()

Tags: python, argparse

With the following code I'm trying to parse multiple arguments which are based on the input of the user. One of those arguments is getting multiple files and reading them using argparse.Filetype('r'). This works fine when getting one file as input, but I'm trying to make it that the scripts can get one or more files, hence the nargs='+'.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='nanana')
parser.add_argument('files', type=argparse.FileType('r'), nargs='+',
                    help='The files which should be converted.')
parser.add_argument("--csvoutput", type=util.str2bool, nargs='?',
                    const=True, default=False, dest='boolean_switch',
                    help="Write file to CSV File.")
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', dest='verbose', action='store_true',
                    help='Enable verbose output.')
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
var = root.tk.splitlist(file_path)
file_list = []
for f in var:
    file_list.append(f)
arguments = parser.parse_args(['--csvoutput', '-v', file_list])
create_file(arguments.files, arguments.boolean_switch)
```

When running this script I get the following error message:

> Convert.py: error: argument files: invalid FileType('r') value:

This is probably because argparse.FileType('r') can't handle a list of files, but I'm not sure what to use otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're literally passing a Python list as `file_list`, so `parse_args` is receiving a nested list instead of a flat list of argv e.g. where it's expecting `['--csvoutput', '-v', 'foo.txt', 'bar.txt']` you're giving it `['--csvoutput', '-v', ['foo.txt', 'bar.txt']]`.

Concatenate the two lists, or (on a recent-enough version of python) unpack `file_list` inside:

```
arguments = parser.parse_args(['--csvoutput', '-v', *file_list])
```